# program name unnecessary to be same as class name- c#

Tags: java, c#

I read in an online article that in java, the program file name should be same as class name. Why is that?
Also in c# i read that program file name need not be same as class name. Why?
Can someone please explain the difference?
Here is a link to the article:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_program_structure.htm

Comment: Both remarks are not true.

Comment: Try [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java8/index.htm) and you will clarify those doubts. As @PatrickHofman has already said, they are not true.

Comment: A _program_ typically uses multiple classes. Do you have the link to the article you mention?

Comment: Hi guys,
this is the link : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_program_structure.htm
Please check the list under "It is worth to note the following points:"
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

A Java class file can contain multiple classes and you can name them whatever you want.

But ideally, following the best practices, it is better to write one class per file and name the file as per the name of the Class.

Comment: This is not discussed. It doesn't concern the source code file name, but the *program file name*.